# What is the purpose of overriding a trait function with a class value in Scala?

Tags: scala, class, overriding, traits

I am new to Scala. I just wonder why we sometimes, especially in Scala API, override trait function with a class value like the example below:

```
sealed trait Amount {
  def amount: Double
}

case class Percentage(amount: Double) extends Amount {
  override def toString = s"$amount%"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

You have a `def` in the trait or superclass because it allows different implementations in the inheriting classes/traits; it is allowed to be overridden with a `val` because otherwise you'd have to write

```
case class Percentage(_amount: Double) extends Amount {
  def amount = _amount
  override def toString = s"$amount%"
}
```

and this would happen quite often, resulting in a lot of non-useful code.

Comment: It's also important to note that in this case, `amount` isn't even defined in the trait, making it more or less equivalent to an `abstract` method in a Java class/interface, which would have to be overwritten by the implementing class anyway.

Comment: FTR, on my to-do list is to figure out whether spec actually says why vals override defs. The spec is the definition of "matching" members here http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#class-members